# .NET: Managing Runtime Dependencies in Dependent Projects

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, csproj

I have two projects, Project A and Project B, where Project B depends on Project A. Project A has a runtime dependency called EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll, which is not required during compile time but is necessary for runtime execution.

After building Project B, its output includes all compile time dependencies except EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll. However, Project A's output does include EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll.

Project B references Project A using the following code snippet:

```
<ProjectReference Include="A.csproj" />
```

To ensure proper execution of Project B, I have considered two approaches:

1. Explicitly defining EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll in Project B.
2. Copying the entire output folder of Project A to Project B's output folder in the PostBuild step.

Each approach has its drawbacks:

1. Approach #1: Managing runtime dependencies becomes challenging as the project grows, and Project B becomes responsible for maintaining all runtime dependencies of any dependent projects.
2. Approach #2: As the project grows, it requires copying other projects as well, leading to duplication with the existing ProjectReference.

I'm looking for a more elegant solution to resolve this issue. If there isn't one, which of the two approaches mentioned above would be preferable?

Comment: You won't have many cases of Runtime-only dependencies. It is uncommon. Approach 2 is overkill and will cause other issues like overwriting files with incorrect versions. Use Approach 1 or a custom copy step that only copies EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll, not the entire output.

Comment: But what if another team want to make use of Project B but they don't know there is a runtime dependency on Project A. When they are referencing the project B, it will fail. If we adopt approach #2, the project C just needs to copy entire output from Project B then it will be confident that they have all needed assemblies for any depent projects of project B.

Comment: That the knowledge of the runtime dependency is not encapsulated within Project B (i.e. a project using project B needs to know about the runtime dependency) is an issue with both approaches. Whether the consuming project has its own references or makes a copy of the entire output, the consuming project is still being changed because it uses Project B. Copying the entire output is more 'work' (and time) than just copying the actual required files and that may be an acceptable trade-off. (Continued in next comment...)

Comment: However, a problem with copying the entire output is that you may actually increase the manual maintenance issue instead of decreasing it. One scenario: If Project A and Project B both use a certain NuGet package, they could require different versions of the package. NuGet will figure out the minimum version that will support projects A and B. If A requires a higher version than B, copying the entire output of B will overwrite the local output copy of the package in A with a lower version.

Comment: This is a great point, the dll conflict during copying over is a big concern that I was not aware of.